# How to upload modify file in my main branch

Tags: github

I have two branches '465_final'(main branch) and 'final_ver2'

final_ver2 is the newest files I have.

I want to replace all new files in 'final_ver2' to main branch '465_final'

What command should i use to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try "git merge".  Visit https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge.

Firstly you should go the your main branch which is called 465_final, then you run this command:

> 1. git checkout 465_final
> 2. git merge final_ver2

Answer (score 0):

Before you merge commit all changes to final_ver2. Then after that switch to the main branch(465_final)

When at branch 465_final just run the following command

> git merge final_ver2